# Take info from database to array

Tags: php, mysql

Hello stackowerflow people, i need to get array from database, that my variable would look like this `$TaskArray['task_id']['task_start_date']` but i dont know how. Maby you guys can help me. Here is the picture of my database 
[image]

Ive tried doing this, but that ddnt worked. Help please.

```
  $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT task_id, task_start_date FROM dotp_tasks");
  if ($query1) {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
        $TaskArray['dbc'] = $row['task_id'];
        $TaskArray['dbc']['task_start_date'] = $row['task_start_date'];
      }
  } else {
```

Comment: What exactly should the result be? An array with the task ID as the key and the date as value?

Comment: that is `task_id` should be dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have multi-dimensional array with an array of each task.

```
...
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT task_id, task_start_date FROM dotp_tasks");
  if ($query1) {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {            
        $TaskArray[$row['task_id']]['task_start_date'] = $row['task_start_date'];
      }
  } else {
...
```

Here, we are generating a multi-dimensional array with `task_id` as key to each array and that array should contain task details.

Try printing the newly generated array using:

```
<?php echo '<pre>'; print_r($TaskArray);echo '</pre>';?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, this should work:

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT task_id, task_start_date FROM dotp_tasks");
if ($query1) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
      $TaskArray[$row['task_id']] = $row['task_start_date'];
    }
} else {
```